# Class static getter which returns class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, es6-class

I have some code:

```
//Main class
class Tools { 

  //Subclass implemented by static getter 
  static get SUPPORTED_UNITS () {
    return class {  
      //Another one
      static get Size () {
        return class {
          //Some data (constants in my case)
        };
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I want to use it like `Tools.SUPPORTED_UNITS.Size` and I want to receive some data as a result of it.
I use WebStorm for writing JavaScript code, so it shows me this when I tried to use it.

[image: Screenshot of error]

I don't know exactly, maybe I just haven't done some setup to my WebStorm, but.. What I need to do that I can use construction like `Class.Subclass.SubClassMethod/SubSubclass`.

I need that:

- It be not a method
- It be static
- It be immutable (without Object.freeze or something like that) - so I can't change my `Class.Subclass` by typing `Class.Subclass = foo;`
- It be indexing by IDE - so I have some help from IDE (like I type `Class.Su` and she suggest `Class.Subclass`)

Is it real in ES6 and WebStorm? Or maybe I have to use ES7 and Babel or someting like that?

P.S. That code is **working**, but I need suggestions from IDE or it will be like a hell.

Comment: Since the code is workable and doesn't use ES2016+ features, you can be sure that it's proper ES6, and the problem is specific to the IDE. The code doesn't explain why a class should be defined *inside* a method, this possibly results in XY problem.

Comment: Don't use classes if you only implement static methods. Use a normal object instead: `const Tools = {SUPPORTED_UNITS: {Size: {}}}`. You can define getters on objects too if you need that. I recommend to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . Also, what you implement is not a "subclass". A subclass is usually a class that *extends* a base class.

Comment: @estus I think it's needed a subclasses for using getters which not allow to change data inside. Maybe I think wrong (it's normal because I just starting to go deep). So how I need to write my class to use immutable static data? Example: `Tools.SUPPORTED_UNITS.Size` where I **can't** change anything (write `Tools.SUPPORTED_UNITS = foo`). Thanks

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your comment. So you offer to use const object for replacing with some kind of static class? **P.S.** Nested class, of course, sorry...

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Add Object.freeze to taste. You may also reconsider why exactly you need it to be read-only. If it doesn't really help anything and results in extra amounts of code, that's a subject for Occam's razor.

Comment: I'm saying if you never *instantiate* a class (i.e. call `new MyClass()`), then don't use a class. Use an object instead (because that's what you are actually after in that case).

Comment: @estus It's kinda class-helper or class-tool which contains some useful constants and method, but it should be like a static class in C# or similar languages. No instance of this class **never** be created. I'm kinda new in JavaScript, so I can think wrong :)

Comment: @FelixKling I need something similar (or actually is) with `static class` from C#. No instance of this class **never** be created. But I need suggestions from IDE anyway (because of this object will be very useful and will be used often). Do you have some code snippet to I fully understand what you talking about?

Comment: It looks like you're overthinking it. The reason why you're using classes in C# is because there are no separate entity for plain objects. And there are plain objects in JS. Unless you have real issues with accidental reassigning  of properties, they shouldn't be restricted. If you need access control at language level, take a look at Typescript (it has `readonly` types; also it has `namespace` that would be appropriate for Tools).

Comment: @estus maybe. So, how I need to write my code to give my IDE opportunity  to suggests me fields and methods? :) Just like usual object?

Comment: Likely yes. Try it. Also, Typescript naturally has *much* better support for IDE autocomplete than JS, it's one of the primary reasons to choose it.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at JSDoc for JS, this improves autocompletion.

Comment: "It's kinda class-helper or class-tool which contains some useful constants and method" - then how about an ES6 module which exports a SUPPORTED_UNITS object?

Comment: @le_m I wanna have one ES6 module for all of this, but, maybe, it's pretty huge. So, I'll think about it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @estus and @Felix Kling suggestion... (likely being misrepresented here)

```
const TOOLS = {
    get SUPPORTED_UNITS() {
        return {
            get SIZE() {
                return {
                    get Bar() { 
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
console.log(TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS.SIZE.Bar) // 1;

TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS.SIZE = "Hello";
// TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS.SIZE = "Hello";
//                            ^
// TypeError: Cannot set property SIZE of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

That works but as remarked by @bergi, it creates a new object in every lookup:

```
console.log(TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS === TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS); // false
```

Yep...

An alternative still using getters would be encapsulate all those objects in an IIFE:

```
const TOOLS = (function () {
    const SIZE = {
        get Bar() { return 1; }
    }
    const SUPPORTED_UNITS = {
        get SIZE() {
            return SIZE;
        }
    }
    return {
        get SUPPORTED_UNITS() {
            return SUPPORTED_UNITS;
        }
    }
}());

console.log(TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS.SIZE.Bar === TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS.SIZE.Bar); // true
console.log(TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS.SIZE === TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS.SIZE);  // true
console.log(TOOLS === TOOLS); // true

TOOLS.SUPPORTED_UNITS = "hello"; // still throws an error
```

> Third update:

The second example solves the issue related to creation of a new object every lookup but it also does not take in consideration that the access to every nested property results in a function call to reevaluate something that is not supposed to change:

```
//A naive measurement:
for(let counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
    let start = Date.now();    
    for(let i = 0; i < 200000; i++){
        let somevar = Tools.SUPPORT_UNITS.SIZE;
    }
    let end = Date.now();
    console.log(`Elapsed using nested getters: ${end - start}ms.`);
}
// Something like:
/** Elapsed using nested getters: 20ms.
 * Elapsed using nested getters: 14ms.
 * Elapsed using nested getters: 9ms.
 * Elapsed using nested getters: 10ms.
 * Elapsed using nested getters: 10ms.
 *
 // While the same as ordinary properties:
 * Elapsed ordinary properties: 2ms.
 * Elapsed ordinary properties: 5ms.
 * Elapsed ordinary properties: 1ms.
 * Elapsed ordinary properties: 0ms.
 * Elapsed ordinary properties: 0ms.
 */
```

So it is also better to check alternatives before using this approach if running 200000 times loops is in the foreseeable future.

Comment: You surely don't even want to use getters. They would re-create the object on every access.

Comment: @betadeveloper What do you think about using deepFreeze fucntion? Make an object, deepFreezed it => gave something like static object

Comment: The result of the standard Object.freeze is a shallow frozen object,  you would have to implement a deepFreeze yourself or find a library. Also, is better to check the warning in the MDN page : "To make an object constant, recursively freeze each property which is of type object (deep freeze).  **Use the pattern on a case-by-case basis based on your design when you know the object contains no cycles in the reference graph, otherwise an endless loop will be triggered.   **